# WSP Builder copies dlls to solution regardless of "Copy Local" property set to False or not

Tags: 2007, solution-package, wspbuilder, gac

I have a Custom timer job that references few custom dlls, now if I set copy local property of these dlls to false, it stills adds them and when I deploy solution it forces them into Gac.

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at bin/debug files and find custom dlls already there, I deleted them and rebuild wsp file solved the problem.